# Selenium looping with spans

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

i am new with selenium. I want to make a loop with spans. It should start with A character. 0-9 shouldnt be got in loop.

```
<div id="alpha">
     <div class="alphabets">
         <span  data-value="0-9" class="alphabetSearch">0-9</span>
         <span  data-value="A" class="alphabetSearch active">A</span>
         <span  data-value="B" class="alphabetSearch">B</span>
         <span  data-value="C" class="alphabetSearch">C</span>
         <span  data-value="Ç" class="alphabetSearch">Ç</span>
         <span  data-value="D" class="alphabetSearch">D</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the issue here, you can find all the elements with span tag and store them in a `List<WebElement>` and then you can just iterate through the list and remove the one which you don't want.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question. Your previous questions is very similar .. just modify the code to fit this case

Answer (score 1):

i am just providing some logic in java here.. i used xpath to collect required span elements, you can use any other appropriate locator.

```
//in java
List<WebElement> allalphabets=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='alpha']/div/span"));

  //starting from j=1, as 0 is for '0-9' which should not be in loop
  for(int j=1; j<allalphabets.size();j++){

      //do your logic here
      //just to print text
      System.out.println(allalphabets.get(j).getText());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
List<WebElement> allspan= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#alpha>div>span"));

for (WebElement spanvalues: allspan) {

    if(spanvalues.getText().equals("0-9")){         
        continue;
    }       

   else{

       //do your code
   }
}
```